# I installed Android Studio IDE but new project won't run

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-studio

I installed `Android Studio` IDE. In first run every thing was OK and it ran smoothly, but after closing it and ruining it again, when I click "New Project" Nothing happens. and by nothing I really means nothing, no error, no force close, nothing.

I tried installing `JDK` and `Android Studio` and every thing again, but again nothing happened.

please help me!

INSTALLED IN WIN 8.1

[Image provided.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cuKI.jpg)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve that.

Because of Sanction of IRAN, I had to download Android Studio from some Other site, that seems to be corrupted, After Downloading Android Studio From Google, the Problem Was Solved!

:)